# Error in LIMIT start : Successfully created in local but not in server

Tags: mysql

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `ujp_get_all_comp_grid_limit`(
IN sp_start INT,
IN sp_max INT
)
BEGIN
SELECT er.employer_comp_name , er.employer_contact_person , er.employer_mob_no,count(ep.job_post_id) ,ep.employer_id,count(ea.candidate_applied_id)
FROM tbl_employer_registration er INNER JOIN tbl_employer_login el ON er.employer_id=el.employer_id  LEFT JOIN tbl_employer_post_details ep ON er.employer_id=ep.employer_id LEFT JOIN tbl_employee_applied ea ON ep.job_post_id=ea.job_post_id WHERE   el.employer_status=1 GROUP BY er.employer_id
LIMIT sp_start,sp_max;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'sp_start,sp_max; END' at line 8

Comment: Read the error. It is actually saying what's wrong.

Comment: What **exact** version of MySQL are you using on the **server**?

Comment: Software version: 5.0.91

Comment: @peterm: I didn't get the error when i removed the limit section the procedure worked properly.

Comment: @LekhulalMathalipara See my answer. It's because the usage of parameters or local variables in LIMIT is prohibited prior to the version 5.5.6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is caused by the fact that the version of MySQL on your server doesn't support route parameters or variables in `LIMIT` clause. The usage of routine parameters in `LIMIT` is allowed only in MySQL 5.5.6 and up.

> **[SELECT Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/select.html)**
>   Within stored programs, LIMIT parameters can be specified using
>   integer-valued routine parameters or local variables **as of MySQL
>   5.5.6**.

If possible update MySQL on the server or you can use dynamic SQL as a workaround on versions prior to 5.5.6.

Answer (score 0):

I think it works if you modify your code like this:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `ujp_get_all_comp_grid_limit`(
    IN sp_start INT,
    IN sp_max INT
)
BEGIN
SET @_sp_start = sp_start;
SET @_sp_max = sp_max;
PREPARE stmt FROM "SELECT er.employer_comp_name , er.employer_contact_person , er.employer_mob_no,count(ep.job_post_id) ,ep.employer_id,count(ea.candidate_applied_id)
    FROM tbl_employer_registration er INNER JOIN tbl_employer_login el ON er.employer_id=el.employer_id  LEFT JOIN tbl_employer_post_details ep ON er.employer_id=ep.employer_id LEFT JOIN tbl_employee_applied ea ON ep.job_post_id=ea.job_post_id WHERE   el.employer_status=1 GROUP BY er.employer_id
    LIMIT ?,?;"; 
EXECUTE stmt USING @_sp_start,@_sp_max;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: Thank you .. im also applied same thing.. dynamic query is working properly.. but is there any issues while using dynamic query?